# Displaying data from database

Tags: 7, forms, database

I am studying how to create a custom module in Drupal7, so far I have created a simple module that will accept subscribers by registering.

These are the fields I have for my database, and has finished the function that will accept user input.

**Table: simple_subscribe**

```
sid , firstname, lastname, email
```

I then proceeded to create the function that will display all of the subscribers
so far this is what I got

```
function subscription_view_form() {
  $result = db_query("SELECT * from subscribe");

  $record = $result->fetchAll();  
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($record);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

I am using `print_r($record);` to display the information, but all it displays is the objects on top of the website, before the navigation

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sid] => 1
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Doe
            [email] => johndoe@gmale.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sid] => 2
            [firstname] => Test
            [lastname] => Beta
            [email] => betatester@delta.com
        )

)
```

**edit**

I am using the hook_menu() to display a form on /subscriptions but I can't output the subscribers inside the content area, I also wanted to list it in a table, I only did the `print_r($records)` to test if it is fetching the data. I wanted to know how to output it properly inside the content area not above it?

```
function subscription_menu() {
  $items[ 'subscriptions' ] = array( 
    'title' => 'View the Subscribers', 
    'description' => 'Subscription form available for subscribers',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array( 'subscription_view_form' ),
    'access arguments' => array( 'access content' ),
    'file' => 'subscription.pages.inc'
  );

  return $items;
```

Comment: what's your specific question?   your code is working as you've told it to.  print_r() is going to print when the function is run.

Comment: indeed. so are we to assume that `subscription_view_form()` is a `page callback` in a `hook_menu()` item? if so, it is supposed to return information, not print it directly; otherwise, yes, this is exactly what will happen.  or is it being called somehow or somewhere else.  a lot more detail is going to be needed to help you out further.

Comment: @jdu I have edited my question and added more explanation.

Comment: @Jimajamma I used hook_menu() but I am not aware of how to output it properly, I forgot to mention I was using print_r for testing, because I don't know how to display it inside the content area. Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you should dive into Drupal's [Examples Module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) to look at how a lot of the hooks and so forth you are (mis)using actually work.

But, quickly:

```
function subscription_menu() {

  $items=array();

  $items[ 'subscriptions' ] = array( 
    'title' => 'View the Subscribers', 
    'description' => 'Subscription form available for subscribers',
    'page callback' => 'subscription_records',
    'access arguments' => array( 'access content' ),
    'file' => 'subscription.pages.inc'
  );

  return $items;

}
```

and

```
function subscription_records() {

  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {subscribe}');
  $records = $result->fetchAll();

  $content = '<pre>' . print_r($records, TRUE) . '</pre>';

  return $content;

}
```

clean up most of the glaring misunderstandings.

However, you will still need to look into [Render Arrays](https://drupal.org/node/930760) and [Dynamic Queries](https://drupal.org/node/310075) to really clean up your code, as well as the [Drupal Theming Guide](https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7) with special attention to [theme_table()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) to create the page you seem to be after.  And, of course, if you need user input, the [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) is a must. But, once again, all of these are explained and demonstrated in the [Examples Module](https://drupal.org/project/examples).